# Loop for a string with inbuilt macro with multiple validations

Tags: excel, loops, iteration, vba

I am fresh to VBA. Therefore have difficulties of getting some essential things out of code.

I have a macros written for two strings. The first string is a string with values I am validating, and the second string, following the first one, is full with validation messages.
What I need to do is built a loop, which would reiterate written macros to next strings if they are filled with data. Picture attached.

E.G. now I have strings populated = A7:G7 and A8:G8, I need to populate next strings A9:G9 and A10:G10

[image: excel sample]

Code sample:

```
'Field 2 (E7) should not exceed 52 characters, it should not be blank'
    If Len(oCell) < 52 And Len(oCell) <> 0 Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tool").Range("E8").Value = ""

    ElseIf Len(oCell) > 52 And Len(oCell) <> 0 Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tool").Range("E8").Value = "Exceeding"

    Else: ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tool").Range("E8").Value = "Cannot be blank"


End If
        End With
```

[image]

I hope that makes sense. Thank you

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZibW.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZibW.jpg)

[enter image description here][2]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZibW.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZibW.jpg)

Comment: Sorry but that doesn't make sense to me. Your picture contains lots of blank cells. What exactly is your question?

Comment: Hi, I have just attached a new picture, where I filled the strings with data. Question is: If I have string field with data A9 to G9, how do I validate, re-run written macros

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you're trying to make a loop (your example uses specifically cell E8) and are unsure how to make that happen.  The basic For loop to going through rows would be structured like:

```
Dim i as Long, lr as Long
lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'Dynamically finds last row, based on column 1 (A)
For i = 8 to lr Step 1
    'Do something using i
Next i
```

---

We can now fix your code to utilize i, such that:

```
Sheets("Tool").Range("E" & i).Value = ""
```

or

```
Sheets("Tool").Cells(i, "E").Value = ""
```

---

In looking at your example, I'm a bit confused... what is oCell (specifically what column), and where is the output supposed to be?

I looks like, from your example, that E7 is being evaluated and the output is in E8... are you going through columns, or down rows?  Need more info about your source data.

---

**Edit:**

```
Dim i as Long, lr as Long
lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'Dynamically finds last row, based on column 1 (A)
For i = 8 to lr Step 2
    If len(Cells(i-1,5)) < 52 AND len(Cells(i-1,5)) <> 0 then
        Sheets("Tool").Cells(i,5).Value = ""
    ElseIf len(Cells(i-1,5)) > 52 then
        Sheets("Tool").Cells(i,5).Value = "Exceeding"
    End If
        Sheets("Tool").Cells(i,5).Value = "Cannot be blank"
Next i
```

---

**Edit 2: This code goes DOWN column E**

```
Dim i As Long, lr As Long
lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'Dynamically finds last row, based on column 1 (A)
For i = 7 To lr Step 2
    Select Case Len(Cells(i, 5))
        Case 0
            Cells(i + 1, 5).Value = "Cannot be blank"
        Case Is < 52
            Cells(i + 1, 5).Value = ""
        Case Is > 52
            Cells(i + 1, 5).Value = "Exceeded"
    End Select
Next i
```

---

**Edit 3: This code goes RIGHT on row 7**

```
Dim i As Long, lc As Long
lc = Cells(5, Columns.Count).End(xltoLeft).Column
For i = 4 To lc Step 1 'looks like you're going 1 by 1 across row 7
    Select Case Len(Cells(7, i))
        Case 0
            Cells(8, i).Value = "Cannot be blank"
        Case Is < 52
            Cells(8, i).Value = ""
        Case Is > 52
            Cells(8, i).Value = "Exceeded"
    End Select
Next i
```

---

**Edit 4: This code goes DOWN and to the RIGHT**

```
Dim i As Long, j As Long, lr As Long, lc As Long
lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row 'Based on last row in column D
'lc = Cells(5, Rows.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'Based on last column in row 5 'Not needed, commented out, known end in Column 68
For i = 7 To lr Step 2
    For j = 4 to 68 Step 1 'From D (4) to BP (68)
        Select Case Len(Cells(i, j))
            Case 0
                Cells(i + 1, j).Value = "Cannot be blank"
            Case Is < 52
                Cells(i + 1, j).Value = ""
            Case Is > 52
                Cells(i + 1, j).Value = "Exceeded"
        End Select
    Next j
Next i
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, E7 is input, and E8 is output. Sorry, I forgot to copy: oCell = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tool").Range("E7").Value. I am going through down rows. My source data will be copied from another sheet, I have written mapping, but only for these two strings, need to think about that too

Comment: @inconsistent So you will be assessing source data E7 and outputting on E8.  Will you then be assessing E9, output on E10, assessing E11, output on E12?

Comment: Yes ) exactly, that is my plan

Comment: @inconsistent Then you use Step 2 in the For loop, to perform the action every other step of the loop.  You then will need your if statement to be reliant on i-1 and your output to be on i.  Make sure that your loop goes to last row + 1.

Comment: Thank you, but I somehow fail to implement this so far. Would be very kind of you to give a written example

Comment: @inconsistent See Edit.  oCell needed to be spelled out to use it in the For loop, and to make it skip rows, the Step was changed to 2.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. Validation stops working

Comment: @inconsistent does column A have contiguous data to the end?  need to verify that the dynamic last row is found appropriately.  when you say 'validation stopped working', can you elaborate further?

Comment: probably I explained wrongly. I've just updated the picture. I start inputing data from column D up to BP. When I say stops validating, I mean stops showing messages in my output string. For this particular example column E, strings E7(input) and E8(output)

Comment: so basically column A is empty

Comment: @inconsistent I've updated the code to use Select Case... and your answer to a question on the 27th appears to be the issue.  You're not going straight down column E, you're going by columns... just takes some changing to the code, but should still be the same base code as Edit 2,

Comment: @inconsistent See edits 2 and 3.  one of those should seemingly fit the bill

Comment: it does not work either :// Maybe there is a way I could use Do while

Comment: @inconsistent you're not performing an ancillary function, so a do while would be inappropriate.  as listed, it should be correct; i've tested both edit 2 and 3, where each works.  Please take a look at the question being asked and possible the information is misleading.  The information I'm seeing is:  1) you're looping through rows OR columns (need to be clear on that), 2) you need to perform a check to count based on the LEN of a given cell.  If you could show some data in your images, it would be appreciated; then we cna figure out more information about the output you need.

Comment: thank you, the last Edit 3 works. However, how could I use Loop for my entire code, from D to BP. How do I surround it? :)

Comment: 1) I have a long string from cell D7:BP7 full with different data, this data I am validating in the string underneath D8:BP8. 2) I have written all the validations, they are very different, sometimes I am checking for number of characters, sometimes I am checking if the cell was populated only with the certain value or if it is or not empty.My main task is to make the loop so I don't have to re-write the entire macro for the next strings, because I would populate the next string with data and validate it again. I am attaching new picture.

Comment: @inconsistent I have the dynamic column count in Edit 3... it's using Row 5 to find the last column; ensure that is the row with all of your headers.  That should take you from (per the loop) column 4 ("D") all the way to the end of your headers (assumed column "DP").

Comment: thank you, that works, but that's not what I need. I need to loop the entire row with range D7:BP7 and validations D8:BP8 down

Comment: @inconsistent See edit 4... you want a combo for all cells in the row.  just did a nested loop to go between the cells of a row per every other row.

Comment: I appreciate your help enourmously, I am very close to what I need ) Just need to fix the loop in a way so that every column with its definite data and validation is repeated.

Comment: @inconsistent not quite sure i understand your second sentence.  are you saying you need to put in an If-statement to assess Columns to be assessed?  Then you're saying validation, you're referring to having the Select Case apply to the appropriate columns when it loops?

Comment: Yes, the second variant, that's what I need: having the Select Case apply to the appropriate columns when it loops.

Comment: @inconsistent I will suggest using an if-statement, where the TRUE condition uses the Select Case, and the if-statement itself is *If j = 4 OR j = 6 OR etc. Then* so you can have it apply to specific columns.  Typically, I would suggest Select Case for this aspect, but you can only have one action (or function) apply during a Case, so it's a little bit more tedious, but will do the trick.  If you go the route of Select Case for the column #, then you can make the validation-Select Case a function... I will leave that on you for which path to take though.

Comment: Thank you very much for everything, I will try figure out myself how to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

As I have find an ultimate solution to my problem, I decided to share it here in case somebody would face it too.

I was trying to add a loop to my source code, so I would not have to repeat the action. 
The best loop in my case was While, as I did not know exactly how many times I need to reiterate the action.

```
While 'My conditions'
Dim endPoint, validPoint as Long 
   'Code'
endpoint = endpoint + 1
validPoint = validPoint +2
Wend
```

I created conditions
endpoint = 'with my data'
validPoint = 'with my validation messages'

SO the loop would run through data and then validated the data until e.g. all the data is checked.

An example of my code:

```
'Field 1 (D7) can only be populated with NEW or CANC'

If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tool").Range("D" & endPoint).Value = "NEW" Or ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tool").Range("D" & endPoint).Value = "CANC" Then
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tool").Range("D" & validPoint).Value = ""

ElseIf (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tool").Range("D" & endPoint).Value <> "NEW" Or ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tool").Range("D" & endPoint).Value <> "CANC") And (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tool").Range("D" & endPoint).Value) <> 0 Then
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tool").Range("D" & validPoint).Value = "error, wrong format"

Else: ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tool").Range("D" & validPoint).Value = "Cannot be blank"

End If
```

I appreciate the enthusiasm and help I was given by the users of stackoverflow. Thank you folks!